# where do i save a txt file on my computer that i want to open in a c programme to read?

Tags: c

i have to write a code to open a user defined txt file and read off the data in the file into an array and return the number of data points in the array, this is what i have so far...

```
float readdata(char file[30]);

int main(void)
{
char filename[30];

printf("Enter file name:");
scanf("%s", filename);
printf("%s\n", filename);
readdata(filename);

    return 0;
}

float readdata(char file[30])
{
FILE *fp;
int i,n;
float x, y, sigma1, sigma2, myarray[1000][4];
n=0;

fp=fopen(file, "r");
if (fp!=NULL)
{
    printf("file not found");
}
else
{
    for(i=0; !feof(fp); ++i)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%f%f %f%f", &x, &y ,&sigma1, &sigma2);
        myarray[i][0]=x;
        myarray[i][1]=y;
        myarray[i][2]=sigma1;
        myarray[i][3]=sigma2;
        ++n;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
return myarray[1000][3];
```

when i run this it just says (lldb). not sure what that means. also it cant find the file i enter even though it is saved next to the main.c in the same folder.

any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You use which compiler?

Comment: You should specify your compiler and also include your header files in your program

Answer (score 3):

your `if` condition is wrong

it should be

```
  if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("file not found");
        return;
    }
   else
   {
    // read data from file
}
```

Comment: `return;` does not return anything it simply return control to your `calling function.`

Comment: Perhaps the OP was thinking `if(!fp)`, but this is just hopeful conjecture. I did notice, however, that in the original code, a failed open would return an unallocated multidimensional array of `float`s from a function returning only a `float`. Assuming the change is made to return a pointer type, perhaps `return`ing a `NULL` pointer would be helpful to determine success in the calling function. Also, the `else` is seemingly unnecessary if he were to `return` in the fail condition.

Comment: @Rustam ,I'm saying that you will get a warning like `'return' with no value,
in function returning non-void.` when you use `return;`

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to be conform with an operating system requirements. If you're under Windows, on of the best practices is to use AppData folder, for example. If you're under *nix, use home dir (~).

Another good idea is to place the file name as command line parameter so your user can run the program with desired file and/or create custom UI as a wrapper for this command-line program.

Comment: Although the OP did include a small input (max 29) on the filename, testing for (`argc > 1`), and using `argv[1]` would be useful, and could help with paths larger than 29 characters (unless this restriction were relaxed, or changed). I can already see an overflow with an AppData path, i.e. `C:\users\me\AppData\myapp\a.txt`. The unix path would be shorter, however, `~/.myapp/a.txt`. I know I prefer data files to be in proper places as I've mounted different drives for `/usr` and `/home` to reduce drive seek bottlenecks.